# How to use timer to block a program till a bool is changed or timeout c#

Tags: c#, timer, blocking

I'm a bit new in working with timers and blocking operations
I want to implement of method that awaits for a bool variable to change for some time else do something else .
this is my code so far :
this is function that I use to receive messages from another peer

```
private void ScrnSta1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            .
            .
            .

            // testing managament: get Mng IP, switch to Mng IP and try to peerwrite 
            // then check if master receives and send ack back to slave
            // hold on a few sec and if ack was received- ok, otherwise return to main IP;        
            else if (str.Contains("MYmngSettings") && (rbSlave.Checked == true))
            {
                peer.OppositeMngIP = str.Split(':')[1].Split(';')[1];
                peer.SubNet = str.Split(':')[1].Split(';')[0];
                peer.MngIP = peer.FindManagementIP(peer.SubNet);
                WritePeer("testing management...MyMngIP:"+peer.MngIP+"\n");
                peer.SetIP(int.Parse(CtrlPort), peer.OppositeMngIP);

                // while Mng Conformation didnt come and Time Out didnt fire keep on waiting
                MngTimerTest.Enabled = true;
                do
                {
                    //Thread.Sleep(500)?; 

                }
                while ( !peer.managementAck && !peer.MngEventFired);
                MngTimerTest.Enabled = false;
                if (peer.managementAck)
                {
                    WritePeer("Management is working\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    peer.SetIP(int.Parse(CtrlPort), RemoteIP.Text);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    WritePeer("Management failed\n");
                }
                peer.MngEventFired = false;

            }
        }

    // 
    // MngTimerTest
    // 
    this.MngTimerTest.Interval = 2000;
    this.MngTimerTest.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.MngTimerTest_Tick);

    private void MngTimerTest_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MngTimerTest.Enabled = false;

        peer.MngEventFired = true;
    }
```

Now when I run it , It stuck the `while` and don't the reason of that , what am I doing wrong

also What is a better way of doing that type of operations

PS. 
I was trying to search for a similar questions but didn't get nothing although it seems very elementary subject

thanks for the help

Comment: Many solutions, one may be to use ManualResetEvent or if you want to keep that skeleton...make that variables volatile (or enclose your test inside a lock).

Comment: @Adriano Can You give a small code example of what you have in mind :) ?

Comment: It is a standard GUI programming bug.  The UI thread of your program, like any thread, can do only *one* thing at the time.  It is not capable of doing anything else when you put it to sleep or force it to stay stuck in a while loop.  It can't repaint the user interface, it cannot respond to user input, it cannot fire the timer's Tick event.  You need to have *another* thread do the work.  Use the Task class.